# Vercel Edge functions for streaming

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel

I'm getting this error: error - Provided runtime "edge" is not supported. Please leave it empty or choose one of: experimental-edge, nodejs
I followed the docs to the letter so I'm not sure what's up. Could it be because I'm in my local environment?

I changed it to experimental-edge and that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are on a version of Next that supports this (13 up I believe)

`npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest`

Answer (score 0):

You can also upgrade to next.js version 12.3.4, it supports the `experimental-edge` runtime.